# inputting two types ways of answer

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I am designing a simple calculator. There are restrictions, in that the user can either enter `5 5 *` OR `5 * 5`. I don't know how to do it.

My code for it so far is...

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter what you want to calculate");
String line = kb.nextLine();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
int number1 = scan.nextInt();
int number2  = scan.nextInt();
char operator = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

The thing is, in that specific way, if they don't enter (`2 2 
*`) the system crashes. What do I have to modify, so that they can ALSO input `2 * 2`.

Comment: You can always check if second token is int with `scan.hasNextInt()`. But this still will not save you from input like `1 2 3`. To handle such cases you can use regex on entire line to see if it matches `number number symbol OR number symbol number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code to check the possible format and print the values if correct formatted input is entered by the user

```
    int number1 = -1;
    int number2 = -1;
    char operator = ' ';
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter what you want to calculate");

    String line = kb.nextLine();
    String[] pieces = line.split("\\s+");
    boolean parsedInput = true;

    if(pieces.length == 3)
    {
        number1 = pieces[0].matches("\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(pieces[0]) : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        number2 = pieces[1].matches("\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(pieces[1]) : (pieces[2].matches("\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(pieces[2]) : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        operator = pieces[1].matches("\\*|\\-|\\+") ? pieces[1].charAt(0) : (pieces[2].matches("\\*|\\-|\\+") ? pieces[2].charAt(0) : ' ');
        if(operator == ' ' || number1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE || number2 == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            parsedInput = false;
    }

    if(parsedInput)
        System.out.println("Number 1: " + number1 + ", Number 2: " + number2 + ", Operator: " + operator);
    else
        System.out.println("Failed to parse: " + line);
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! did not learn regex yet but i will take a look at it by myself. Also, what should i had there so it does the operations for ^ and /. In that one it only does +, -, *

Comment: its okay i was able to understand it and fix it!

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
int number1 = scan.nextInt();
int number2  = scan.nextInt();
char operator = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

is saying that "expect the second part of the input to be an integer; if it isn't an integer, then there's been an error"

There are two ways to fix this:

1) Write code that looks at the 2nd item, decides if it's an integer or a symbol, then proceed.

2) Or, you can handle the error.  Put a try-catch around the call that can throw the error and then handle the input differently.

```
int number2;
char operator;
try {
    number2  = scan.nextInt();
    operator = scan.next().charAt(0);
    // process the input in this order
    ...
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // process the input in another order
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter what you want to calculate");
        String line = kb.nextLine();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
        String number1 = scan.next();
        String number2  = scan.next();
        char operator = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

After you get the data line you can convert the whole numbers and do the operation as you like